# Angular: How do I keep component state in nested component tree when parent list is replaced

Tags: angular, nested, components

I'm trying to set up an expand/collapse list that has 3 layers of nested children. Each item click will refresh the list. The 'expanded' state is currently being stored in the 'item' component, so when the list is replaced that component is destroyed and loses the 'expanded' state.

### Things I've tried

I've solved a similar problem by extracting the 'group' into its own component, but that was in a list that wasn't nested. I can't seem to extract this 'expanded' flag at a level that is 'above' the entire list

It's going to be a fairly reasonably sized list so I  *could* try and update the list without 'replacing' it but that sounds like a recipe for disaster.

### Sample Item Data

```
{
  "Id": "2",
  "Children": [
    {
      "Id": "2.1",
      "Children": [
        {
          "Id": "2.2",
          "Children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": "2.2",
      "Children": []
    }
  ]
}
```

And then I'm setting up the component recursively

`# item.component.html`

```html
<li>
  <div *ngIf="item.Children.length === 0">{{item.Id}}</div>

  <div *ngIf="item.Children.length > 0">
    <button (click)="expanded = !expanded">{{item.Id}}</button>
    <ul *ngIf="expanded">

      <item
        *ngFor="let subItem of item.Children"
        [item]="subItem">
      </item>

    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```

### Isolated Example

I have an isolated example set up on StackBlitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-components-updated-xavyfe

### Expectations:

I expect the expand/collapse state to stay even when the list is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what `trackBy` is for. With it, Angular will only refresh what needs to be refreshed. I'm assuming `Id` is unique here.

In template:

```
      <item
        *ngFor="let subItem of item.Children; trackBy: trackById"
        [item]="subItem">
      </item>
```

And in TS:

```
  trackById = (item) => item.Id;
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-components-updated-ng4gac

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a trackByFunction into ngFor-directive. Therefore the id of your items should be unique (two times 2.2). Here is a working example of your code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-components-updated-fprktk